# replace the few characters from first and last of string

Tags: javascript

replacing the first and last few characters with the * character, i am able to solve the str1 case. How can i solve the remaining one. Right now i am able to mask the last 4 characters.

how can i mask the first  3 or 4 characters. ? whats wrong in the regex pattern

```js
var str1 = "1234567890123456";
str1 = str1.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");

console.log(str1)

var str2 = "123-456-789-101112"
str2 = str2.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");

console.log(str2) // expected ***-***-***-**1112

var str3 = "abc:def:12324-12356"
str3 = str3.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");

console.log(str3) // expected ***:***:*****-*2356
```

Right now it is masking only the four characters from last, how can i mask 4 characters from front also like

```
1234567890123456 => 1234********3456
123-456-789-101112 => 123-4**-***-**1112
abc:def:12324-12356 => abc:d**:*****-*2356
```

Comment: What's your desired output for those examples, exactly?

Comment: The issue to the second one is that it sees every numbers sperated by a line as own query as far as i could see - If you change {4} to {2} you can see that its only selecting each block as own query and then making the left numbers to a start. i do not know how to fix it but it might help you.

Comment: Why using a regular expression and not just substring/assembling string if you know that you want to mask N chars whatever they are (number, char, specials...) ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated the question

Comment: @CertainPerformance right now it is masking only last four characters but i  want to mask 4 characters from the first also

Comment: @Dario Regular expressions are far terser and are perfectly suited for string matching/manipulation. I'd strongly prefer them over manual string indexing and testing in most cases, for any language.

Comment: @CertainPerformance why the email id's are not masking using the regex pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to lookahead for non-space characters followed by 4 digits. Since you want to replace the alphabetical characters too, use a character set `[a-z\d]` rather than just `\d`:

```js
const repl = str => console.log(str.replace(/[a-z\d](?=\S*\d{4})/g, "*"));

repl("1234567890123456");
repl("123-456-789-101112");
repl("abc:def:12324-12356");
```

If you want to keep the first 4 alphanumeric characters as well, then it's significantly more complicated - match and capture the first 4 characters, possibly interspersed with separators, then capture the in-between characters, then capture the last 4 digits. Use a replacer function to replace all non-separator characters in the second group with `*`s:

```js
const repl = str => console.log(str.replace(
  /((?:[a-z\d][-@.:]?){4})([-@:.a-z\d]+)((?:[a-z\d][-@.:]?){4})/ig,
  (_, g1, g2, g3) => g1 + g2.replace(/[a-z\d]/ig, '*') + g3
));

repl("1234567890123456");
repl("123-456-789-101112");
repl("abc:def:12324-12356");
repl("test@test.com");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but how can i mask the first  4 characters also

Comment: but this case is not working , any idea "read:ABC:12372193128737892173"

Comment: why the regular expression is failing in this case "read:ABC:12372193128737892173"

Comment: That has a capital letter in it. If caps are allowed, add the case-insensitive flag.

Comment: where to add that

Comment: Flags are the characters at the end of a regular expression literal, eg `/g` means global flag. For global and case-insensitive, use `/gi` (of course, you could also repeat `[a-zA-Z...` everywhere but that's repetitive)

Comment: given the gi, but didnt worked , const repl = str => console.log(str.replace(
  /((?:[a-z\d][-:]?){4})([-:a-z\d]+)([a-z\d]{4})/,
  (_, g1, g2, g3) => g1 + g2.replace(/[a-z\d]/gi, '*') + g3
));

Comment: is there any other place where i should give the gi flag

Comment: You forgot to add it to the first regular expression. It should end in `/i` (or `/gi` if there will be multiple sequences like this), not in `/`

Comment: final answer will  const repl = str => console.log(str.replace( /((?:[a-z\d][-:]?){4})([-:a-z\d]+)([a-z\d]{4})/gi, (_, g1, g2, g3) => g1 + g2.replace(/[a-z\d]/gi, '*') + g3 ));, worked for that case also

Comment: i have checked the mail id, but it is not working , "test.test@test.com" , "test@test.com"

Comment: since we have given the a-z it should take isn't, why it is not replacing the alphabets with *

Comment: So now you not only want to change what looks like credit card numbers, but also email addresses? See edit, you didn't specify that `@` was a permitted separator character before - just add it to the character sets. It would also be good to post all your requirements in your question when you post it - don't post [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)